# file not downloading properly

Tags: iphone, xamarin, webclient

I am downloading a file from a url and saving it to a directory on my phone.

the path is: /private/var/mobile/Applications/17E4F0B0-0781-4259-B39D-37057D44B778/Documents/samplefile.txt

However, when i debug the file is created and downloaded. But, when i ad-hoc it and run the file. samplefile.txt is created but it's blank.

Code:

```
String directory = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var filename = Path.Combine (directory, "samplefile.txt");

    if (!File.Exists (filename)) {

        File.Create (filename);

        var webClient = new WebClient ();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => {
            var text = e.Result; // get the downloaded text
            File.WriteAllText (filename, text);                   
        };
        var url = new Uri (/**myURL**/);
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync (url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your sample slightly and the following works for me.

The **StreamReader** is only there just to re-read in the contents of the file to confirm that its the same contents in the file as that of the downloaded file:-

If you put a breakpoint there also you can manually inspect same contents as downloaded.

```
        string directory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filename = Path.Combine(directory, "samplefile.txt");

        if (!File.Exists(filename))
        {

            var webClient = new WebClient();

            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                // Write contents of downloaded file to device:-
                var text = e.Result; // get the downloaded text
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename);
                sw.Write(text);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
                sw = null;

                // Read in contents from device and validate same as downloaded:-
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
                string strFileContentsOnDevice = sr.ReadToEnd();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(strFileContentsOnDevice == text);                    
            };

            var url = new Uri("**url here**, UriKind.Absolute);
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(url);
        }
```

Comment: it works when i debug it. the file is written in the documents and everything works out. but if i adhoc it still messes up.

Comment: what do you mean by adhoc?

Comment: i compile and get an ipa file to install through itunes.

Comment: so it works debugging on emulator and also debugging against a device?, but not when you do your ipa installation separately?

Comment: yup. i've tried a bunch of different approaches. but for some reason an ipa installation is not working.

Comment: if this is the only app that you have a problem with an ipa installation, then perhaps you may want to try further debugging such like putting a listbox on the page, and outputting some information to it to help better diagnose the root cause your experiencing?  Try also putting some exception handling in there and output this so at least the app won't crash to help you better diagnose your issue?